# when i click on a link_to popup still appears on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

i have a problem. when i click on a link_to and get directed to another page on the same website, the popup, where the link_to is, stays open. Does anyone know how to solve this

this is my jQuery/Javascript code

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
  $('#menuModal').hide();
  console.log("realod")
});

$("#buttonmenu").on("click", function () {
  $("#menuModal").show();
  console.log("button_clicked")
})

$("#closemenuBtn").on("click", function () {
  $("#menuModal").hide();
})

$(".link-in-menupopup").on("click", function () {
  $("#menuModal").hide();
})
```

Comment: You probably have modal display:visible on the page that loads

Comment: .hidden{
   display: none;
}